# Stable Homotopy Inequivalence via Steenrod Squares

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

In Example 1.1 of https://maths.dur.ac.uk/users/andrew.lobb/master_morse.pdf it explains why $\mathbb{C}P^2$ and $S^2\vee S^4$ are not stably homotopy equivalent by looking at the second Steenrod squares.

I understand "stable homotopy equivalent" as in https://etale.site/livetex/wcatss/sht1.pdf. That is, $X$ and $Y$ are stable homotopy equivalent if there is a large $m<\infty$ such that the $m$-th suspension of both are homotopy equivalent. In particular, note $S^1$ and $S^2$ would **not** be stably homotopy equivalent in this sense.

I also understand that we can see the second Steenrod squares of both spaces are different because in second cohomology the operation coincides with cup product squaring; if $\alpha$ is the generator of second cohomology, in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ $Sq^2(\alpha)$ equals the top cohomology generator, and in $S^2\vee S^4$ it equals zero.

We also know the second Steenrod square is a stable cohomological operation, that is, it commutes with suspensions, as in https://amathew.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/the-steenrod-algebra-and-its-dual/#more-2962. I understand that this would mean $\Sigma^m (Sq^2_X(\alpha)) = Sq^2_{\Sigma^m X}(\Sigma^m \alpha)\in H^{(m+2)+2}(\Sigma^m X)$, where $\alpha\in H^2(X)$.

**Question:** How do we use this information (the two spaces $\mathbb{C}P^2$ and $S^2\vee S^4$ have distinct second steenrod squares) to show they are not stable homotopy equivalent?
In other words, how do we show from the bare fact that Steenrod squares commute with suspensions that a Steenrod square is a stable homotopy *invariant*? Of course, saying the Steenrod squares are stable cohomology operations is begging the question in this context (i.e. my question is about chasing definitions).

**Side Question:** I feel like some of my "I understand" statements above are not accurate. Please let me know if my definitions are not right.

Comment: Are you asking why the Steenrod squares are homotopy invariants? Once you know that: if there is an $m$ so that $\Sigma^m X$ and $\Sigma^m Y$ are homotopy equivalent, then their mod 2 cohomology is the same, with Steenrod operations taken into account. Then the stable aspect of the Steenrod operations tells you that the same must be true for the cohomology of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: In this concrete example, let's focus on the second Steenrod square. If all I knew is that the Steenrod square is homotopy invariant, showing it's different for $S^2\vee S^4$ and $\mathbb{C}P^2$ would tell me they are not homotopy equivalent, but they could still be stable homotopy equivalent. Now, I heard the Steenrod square is not just a homotopy invariant—it's a *stable* homotopy invariant. I read that all we need for this latter fact is that the Steenrod square commutes with suspensions. So, how do we use the commutativity with suspensions to prove it's a stable homotopy invariant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we know that the action of $\mathop{Sq}^2$ is a homotopy invariant and that it is also stable (compatible with suspension), then we argue by contradiction as follows: assume that there is an $m$ so that $\Sigma^m \mathbb{C}P^2$ and $\Sigma^m (S^2 \vee S^4)$ are homotopy equivalent. We of course know their mod 2 cohomology as vector spaces, and the fact that $\mathop{Sq}^2$ is a homotopy invariant means that we could conclude that this diagram commutes (all cohomology with mod 2 coefficients):
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
H^{m+2} \Sigma^m \mathbb{C}P^2 & \xrightarrow{\cong} & H^{m+2} \Sigma^m (S^2 \vee S^4) \\
\downarrow^{\mathop{Sq}^2} & & \downarrow^{\mathop{Sq}^2} \\
H^{m+4} \Sigma^m \mathbb{C}P^2 & \xrightarrow{\cong} & H^{m+4} \Sigma^m
(S^2 \vee S^4)
\end{array}
$$
The suspension isomorphism and the stability of $\mathop{Sq}^2$ then gives us commuting squares on the left and right sides of this one:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
H^2 \mathbb{C}P^2 & \xrightarrow{\cong} & 
H^{m+2} \Sigma^m \mathbb{C}P^2 & \xrightarrow{\cong} & H^{m+2} \Sigma^m (S^2 \vee S^4) & \xrightarrow{\cong} & H^2 (S^2 \vee S^4) \\
\downarrow^{\mathop{Sq}^2} & & \downarrow^{\mathop{Sq}^2} & & \downarrow^{\mathop{Sq}^2} & & \downarrow^{\mathop{Sq}^2} & & \\
H^4 \mathbb{C}P^2 & \xrightarrow{\cong} & 
H^{m+4} \Sigma^m \mathbb{C}P^2 & \xrightarrow{\cong} & H^{m+4} \Sigma^m
(S^2 \vee S^4) & \xrightarrow{\cong} & H^4 (S^2 \vee S^4) 
\end{array}
$$
Since the resulting diagram does not actually commute (the square formed by the left and right sides of the whole diagram), then the initial assumption must be wrong: we cannot have an $m$ so that $\Sigma^m \mathbb{C}P^2$ and $\Sigma^m (S^2 \vee S^4)$ are homotopy equivalent.